# Upload Image with input file button or drag and drop the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

now I am learning to upload file with HTML5 and JavaScript (JQuery). and I got a problem with it. so, bellow here is the preview of my app.

[image]

and from this app, I want to upload file either you choose file from input button or drag and drop the file in the drop zone.

here is the code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="blah" class="col-lg-4 dropzone" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false">
        <p>Drop Your Image Here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('umum/uploadFile', ['id' => 'form_upload']);?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userfile">File input</label>
                <input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile">
                <p class="help-block">Only image file allowed to upload here.</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then my script :

```
<script>
        // preview the file that will be uploaded
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $('#blah').html('<img src="'+event.target.result+'" alt="your image">');
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        // manual select file from input file button
        $("#userfile").change(function(){
            readURL(this);
        });

        // drag and drop file image
        $(function() {
            $('#blah').bind('dragover', function() {
                $(this).addClass('dropzone-active');
            });
            $('#blah').bind('dragleave', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('dropzone-active');
            });
        });

        function drag_drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // parsing data to preview the file before upload
            readURL(event.dataTransfer);

            // alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
            // alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
            // alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].size+" bytes");
        }
    </script>
```

and the problem is I cannot change the value of the input file button when I drag and drop the image in the drop zone. and of course, I cannot upload the file because the input file remains empty. Btw, I have tried to write `$('#userfile').val(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);` in drag_drop function up there and the result in my console is :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: and FYI, I want to upload the file manually not using AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NB**: Note that [There is no cross-browser way to upload dragged & dropped files without Ajax](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/#article-header-id-4). Also note (and this could be the reason for the limitation) the security implications of trying to assign a value to a file upload input field: if it were possible to programmatically assign values thus, imagine something like:

```
$("input[type=file]").val("passwords.txt");
```

So we **have** to use AJAX. That said, you just have to create a new `FormData` instance and append to it the `dataTransfer.files` property from your drop event:

```
    function drag_drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.each(dataTransfer.files, function(i, file) {
            uploadData.append( "userfile", file);
        });
    }

    var $form = document.querySelector('form'),
    ajaxData = new FormData($form);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: ajaxData,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false // Important for file uploads
    });
```

If your reason for preferring manual uploads is to have all your files uploaded alongside your form when submitted, consider creating a hidden input field and setting its value to the location of the uploaded files when AJAX successfully returns.

You might also want to set the `multiple` attribute in your file input field, given from your code, I see you processing several files.

[Full tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/#article-header-id-4)